# Neo4j - how to change a node from type A to type B

Tags: neo4j

I have some nodes like these:
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (n:Woka) return count (n);

```
+-----------+
| count (n) |
+-----------+
| 19798966  |
+-----------+
1 row
```

How I can change them from "Woka" to "Book" without delete and recreate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use set and remove

```
MATCH (n:Woka)
SET n:Book
REMOVE n:Woka
```